# Accessing C# variable value in ASPX SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have an aspx `SqlDataSource` that I use to insert values into a table to keep track of requests. I authenticate users using LDAP and would like to automatically insert the correct user in the `SubmittedBy` column of my request table.

The user's ID is accessed through a C# variable, `userId`, which I collect during page load.

I'm stuck, however, in how to include that value in my `UpdateCommand`.

Currently I have the following:

```
UpdateCommand="INSERT INTO [EditRequest] ([AppId]
, [SubmittedBy]
, [SourceControlId]
, [RepoLocation], [MainBranch], [isBBLITE], [ResourceDir], [scriptLocation]
, [BarFileLocation], [R9Branch], [auditR9], [R10Branch], [audit10_1], [R10_2Branch]
, [audit10_2], [DateSubmitted], [ExpectedDate]) 

VALUES (@ApplicationId
, **<%=userId%>**
, @SourceControlId
, @RepoLocation, @MainBranch, @isBBLITE, @ResourceDir
, @scriptLocation, @BarFileLocation, @R9Branch, @auditR9, @R10Branch, @audit10_1
, @R10_2Branch, @audit10_2, GETDATE(), GETDATE()+5)">
```

But at runtime it complains about finding a `<` in the SQL statement.

How do I pass `userId` to my `SqlDataSource` `Update` statement?

Comment: I suggest using a query parameter.

Comment: Where are you getting the other parameters from? Why not get the userid from the same place?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
VALUES (@ApplicationId , +"<%=userId%>.val()"+ , @SourceControlId
```

Or you can use `Session` variables in this situation.